# Dynamic Table within Dynamic Table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a dynamic table that is working perfectly but I trying to implement the same table within the cells and for it to have the same functions but in the cell only.  The problem I am having is that when the add row button is pressed on the large table the next row doesn't contain a new dynamic table within the table.  Is there some way to basically call a function within a function to solve this?

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
    <table id="dataTable" width="150px" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td height="84">
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
    <td> <input name="button" type="button" onClick="addRow('dataTable1')" value="Add Row" /> 
      <table id="dataTable1" width="150px" border="1">
        <tr> 
          <td height="27"> 1 </td>
          <td> <input name="text" type="text" /> </td>
          <td> <input name="text" type="text" /> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <script type="text/javascript">

        function addRow1(tableID) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
            firstCell.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;
            var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
            var thirdCell = row.insertCell(2);
            var element = document.createElement("input");
            element.type = "text";
            element.name = "txtbox[]";
            secondCell.appendChild(element);
            var element2 = document.createElement("input");

            element2.type = "text";

            element2.name = "txtbox2[]";

            thirdCell.appendChild(element2);

        }
    </script> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
            firstCell.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;
            var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
            var thirdCell = row.insertCell(2);
            var element = document.createElement("input");
            element.type = "text";
            element.name = "txtbox[]";
            secondCell.appendChild(element);
            var element2 = document.createElement("input");
            element2.type = "text";
            element2.name = "txtbox2[]";
            thirdCell.appendChild(element2);

        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure this is what you were after, but how does this work for you?

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
    <table id="dataTable" width="150px" border="1">
        <tr>
  <td height="84">
      1
  </td>
  <td>
      <input type="text" />
  </td>
    <td> <input name="button" type="button" onClick="addRow('dataTable1')" value="Add Row" /> 
      <table id="dataTable1" width="150px" border="1">
        <tr> 
          <td height="27"> 1 </td>
          <td> <input name="text" type="text" /> </td>
          <td> <input name="text" type="text" /> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var contents = document.getElementById('dataTable').outerHTML;

function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
  firstCell.setAttribute('colspan', 3);
  var newCont = contents.replace(' 1 ', rowCount + 1);
  firstCell.innerHTML = newCont;
}
</script>
```

Comment: ...No im trying to have the new row add a row but also the "add row" button and cells in the new row as well